# Valuation of open FX-Forward

Tags: fx, forward, market-model, fair-value

So called closed FX-Forwards are well known forward contracts where some amount of foreign currency is bought at a specified date in the future for a price fixed "today". Such contracts can be valuated using the well known cost-of-carry formula.

Recently, I learned about **open** FX-forward contracts. In this kind of contract the holder has the flexibility to make as many drawdowns as he wants **during a specified perio**d as long as the full amount is paid by maturity [see e.g. this page](https://www.kantox.com/en/glossary/open-forward-contract/).

What is market practice to value such open FX-forward contracts?

Comment: I feel it could be some sort of average between "closed" FX Fwd quotes. Say we enter into an "open" FX Fwd with two exchange dates: at the 3M & 6M mark. Then in the absence of arbitrage the buyer should be projected to be indifferent to exchanging money at 3M or 6M (as seen from today), since the FX Fwd quotes represent exactly this equilibrium. Hence it should be 50-50 which date he chooses. So the closed quote is the average of the two. Thoughts?

Comment: I wonder whether one could use some dominance argument similar to American options on non-div paying socks which have the same price as European options.

Comment: This could depend on the interest rate differential between the two currencies @Phil-ZXX

Comment: Thinking about it more, you probably need a volatility term-structure model since each "open" date (on which the buyer is allowed to exchange money at the predetermined fx "strike rate") essentially represents an option. So american/bermudan pricing can probably be applied. Perhaps longstaff schwartz or binomial trees are applicable?

Comment: @Phil-ZXX thank you for your comments. So far in the methods you mention the amount at each of the Bermudan dates does not matter ... maybe it should? I wonder whether there exists some market practice - a rule of thumb?

Comment: Haven't traded open FX Forward (so I am just thinking out loud). I'd say the amount does not matter per-se, because if on any "exercise date" your strike is favorable to you then you'd exercise the full amount available. This is similar to commodity swing options (see https://uk.mathworks.com/help/fininst/examples/pricing-swing-options-using-the-longstaff-schwartz-method.html). The difference being that you are not bound by any storage costs and can thus execute the full amount at once.

Comment: Right, this is a bit in the vein of my thoughts of dominance. if one point in time during the period is best then the rational investor settles all at this point in time.

Comment: @Phil-ZXX maybe you want to look at my thoughts in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flexible forward contract is very much like an American option: at each exercise date, you have the choice to receive the payoff $(S-K)$ or not. The difference with a regular option is that you must choose a date.

In effect, this is a classical optimal stochastic control problem and may be solved using exactly the same techniques as for an American (or a Bermudan) option: typically a finite difference method applied to the Black-Scholes PDE with the linear complementary constraint $$f(t_i, s_j) \geq s_j - K$$, where $t_i$ is an exercise date and $s_j$ the asset price in the FDM discretization grid.

In particular the price will depend on the asset volatility, and the contract will have a non-zero vega.

See https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S2424786316500109, https://www.globalcapital.com/article/k6b8msb96708/american-currency-forwards.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your answer:  Suppose you are the holder of the open contract.  You hedge it by executing a vanilla forward at 1.1679 for date 92.   You now have an arbitrage, for if the fx forward for one of the dates 88 to 91 becomes higher than that for date 92, you can switch the hedge to that other date,  This means that the true price of your open contract must be slightly greater than 1.1679.  However, the switch in this case is unlikely, because it would only occur if euro rates exceed usd rates.  It is an option on the rate differential.   If you created an open FX forward on a currency pair where rates are very similar , the effect would be greater.

Comment: Thank you for this remark. By "slightly greater than 1.1679" you mean in order to reflect the option? If so then this would be the new content. The rest is contained in "my answer" below. Do you agree? If you bring up new aspects then I would be happy to read about them. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the excess over 1.1679 is the value of this switch option.  It would be complex to value it precisely.

Comment: The intuition is somewhat right, but the problem is really an optimal control problem, and you need a numerical method to solve the non-linear PDE. The price may be vastly different from 1.1679 and will involve the underlying asset volatility.

Answer (score -1):

I am trying to answer my own question to make discussion possible.

Say we have an open FWD with period $[T_1,T_2]$ in which we can settle it. The strike price $K$ is fixed today.

As a example for EUR USD we have a spot of 1.16 (USD per EUR) and let us assume that the strike price for the above forward is $K = 1.1677$ (we have much higher USD rates than EUR leading to this higher forward price).

Then, on any given day $t$ I can compare this $K$ to the forward prices of forwards that stettle on all the days in the interval $[T_1,T_2]$.

The fair price is 
$$
F_{T_i} = S_t \exp ( (r_d(T_i)-r_f (T_i))\cdot (T_i-t)/365  )
$$
and a rational agent will settle when the gains are highest thus at
$$
T^* = \arg max_{t \in [T_1,T_2]} \{ F_{T_i}-K  \}.
$$
Thus the price $K$ has to equal this one $F_{T^*}$. If the ir-differential does not changes too much during $[T_1,T_2]$ then I assume that this $T^*$ will be the first of the last day of the period depending on the sign of the differential.

Continuing the example we can calculate the forward prices (crudely) for some $T_i$:

- $T_i = 88$ then $F_{88} \approx 1.1675$ and the gain is $-0.00017$
- $T_i = 90$ then $F_{90} \approx 1.1677$ gain is zero.
- $T_i = 92$ then $F_{92} \approx 1.1679$ gain is approx $0.00017$

Thus if the period is $\{88, 89, 90, 91, 92\}$ the price of the open forward should be $K=1.1679$, which is the forward price for settlement at the last day of the period as the interest rate differential between USD and EUR (USD-EUR ir) is positive.

Comment: The problem to solve is an optimal control problem, the reasoning here leads to a lower bound, but underestimate the true price of the contract.