Pricing FX Flexi-Forward: Fixed Strikes per Month to Unwind Position
Say I have a client who wants to purchase an FX flexi-forward with a maturity of a year, but they want to fix the prices at which they can unwind their position each month; as in they can unwind up to the full notional amount of their position on the last day of January at a specific strike rate, for example. Essentially what the client is asking for is the option - but not the obligation - to buy up to the notional amount of $C_{Y}$ with $C_{x}$ at a pre-defined strike-rate $S_{month}$, for every month up until the end of the forward.
My question is about how to price this FX Flexi-Forward, and if there would be any way to set up exactly the same type of structure, using Partially Executable European Call Options alongside Compound Options instead? To clarify, would selling the client a Partially Executable European Call Option, alongside a Compound Option that would allow them to buy another Partially Executable European Call Option for the following month at a predefined strike-rate, with $Notional_{0}-Executed_{0}$, as well as a compound option that would allow him to do the same thing next month with his pre-defined rates, be equivalent?
Thank you in advance.

https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/65705/54838 might help
